# DAGGER: Error cannot resolve "this" when trying to inject into Fragment?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I get a "cannot resolve method" error on this line:

```
AndroidInjection.inject(this);
```

I am trying to inject into a fragment. Here is the whole class:

```
public class ShowWalletFragment extends BaseFragment {

    @Inject
    ShowWalletViewModelFactory showWalletViewModelFactory;
    ShowWalletViewModel showWalletViewModel;
    private Wallet wallet;
    private static final String TITLE_BALANCE = "Balance";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        //butterknife bind
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        showWalletViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, showWalletViewModelFactory).
                get(ShowWalletViewModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

}
```

Why can't it resolve "this" ? Any suggestions? If you need more code from my app please let me know.

EDIT1:

```
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.19'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.19'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.19'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.19'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.19'
```

Comment: Do you have dagger-android dependency added to your build.gradle file?

Comment: It isn't have problems with this, its having problems finding the inject function.  Make sure that exists, for the correct type.  Also, until you build for the first time some Dagger files aren't written and may not be found, building fixes that.

Comment: @mayosk Yes, I do. I have added them to my question under EDIT1. Please, can you take a look?

Comment: @GabeSechan Could you explain further, please? I don't understand what you mean with having problems with inject function. Should I look for problems in my application class, or component? For activities, Dagger is working. But not for fragments. Also, Yes, Dagger files is missing right now because I can't build without errors anymore. But Was working for activities. Problem appeared after I tried to add fragments to my app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this

```
import dagger.android.support.AndroidSupportInjection

AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
```

Comment: I hope ur using support fragment

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did manage to solve it, but your comment (not the answer, but the comment about support fragment) is correct. I had my imports mixed up. But the comment is correct so I will upvote and hope it will help someone else in the future. Thanks again!